# phonegap - where is the file saved?

Tags: file, cordova, filewriter

I'm want to save an file with text in my phonegap app. I'm using the exaple code from [phonegap - FileWriter_full_example](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileWriter_full_example). 
Where is the file readme.txt located after writing? When I'm seraching after 'renamed.txt' at the windows explorer i get an not found error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The File gets stored in sdcard.

Go to File Explorer--->mnt---->sdcard

And you will get the file there...